# Oracle SQL -> Select row where ID is in Long txt File -> string literal too long

Tags: sql, oracle

txt file that contains ~30k of comma seperated IDs

for small .txt files containing less than 100 IDs I used this simple Query:

```
select * from employee
where employee.id in ('123', '456', '478', '658')
```

When I now paste the content of the 30k IDs in my .sql file I get the following error:

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
Error at Line: 7 Column: 20
```

Can someone help me how I can use another data Type.
It would be good if it would still be possible to just copy and paste the long list of comma separated values into the SQL script.

Comment: This link could help you.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=want-to-have-1000-values-in-in-operator

Comment: Incidentally, the error you're getting suggests you're doing `in ('123, 456, 478, 658)` with a single string value, rather than `in ('123', '456', '478', '658')` with multiple values; but you'd hit the 1000-element limit anyway, whether you were passing multiple strings or multiple numbers. Is your text file on the DB server where it can be picked up to be used as an external table, or only on a client machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a collection and a table collection expression:

```
select * from employee
where employee.id in (select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('123', '456', '478', '658')))
```

Or preferably, as they are numbers:

```
select * from employee
where employee.id in (select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(123, 456, 478, 658)))
```

Or you could turn that into a CTE and join to it:

```
select e.*
from (
  select *
  from table(sys.odcinumberlist(123, 456, 478, 658))
) t
join employee e on e.id = t.column_value
```

You could also create a numeric table type and use that with `member of` instead of `in`:

```
create type mynumbertable as table of number;

select * from employee
where employee.id member of (mynumbertable('123', '456', '478', '658'));
```

... but that might be overkill for an ad hoc task.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fb96908800c04a2a9a78b52e7fa33cec)

Or, of course, put the values into a real table (which could be a temporary table) and join to that, but that doesn't really work for your copy-and-paste scenario.

Comment: I would second @Alex Poole suggestion for a "real" table.  It could also be an external table.  The key is going to be where do these values originate, and how you decided that a copy and paste of a comma-delimited list was the preferable solution. If you could get the values as a file where each value is a record, instead of a delimited string, it would be drop dead simple with an external table: SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE E WHERE E.EMPID NOT IN (SELECT EMP_ID FROM MY_EXT_TBL);